# Qt - QTimeEdit as a timer viewer

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I have a QTimeEdit which I want to set to some value and the each second I want to decrease by 1 the value that shows the QTimeEdit. So when it will be 0, the I want to have a QMeesageBox that says "Your time is off.". Can I some how do this with QTimeEdit interface, or I should use QTimer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QTimeEdit` for displaying the time but you will have to use `QTimer` to decrease the time every second.

You can do something like this:

```
timeEdit->setTime(...); //set initial time
QTimer timer;
timer.start(1000); //timer will emit timeout() every second
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotTimeout()));

void slotTimeout()
{
    QTime time = timeEdit->time().addSecs(-1);
    timeEdit->setTime(time);

    if (time == QTime(0, 0))
        //time is zero, show message box
}
```

Comment: addSecs(int s) does not work. I am using Qt 4.6.2. Has anyone encountered to this problem?

Comment: Also I have put 2 minutes, it comes to 0 sec and there is no entrance to the "if" statement. Can't understand why.

Comment: When I use QTime its "mds" field is becoming -1. So you need to call QTime(0,0) constructor! Please change your answer in order to accept it. 
BTW where are my votes?? :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I really should check my answers before posting them:) It's fixed now. What votes do you mean?

Comment: On the answer? Well I guess somebody downvoted it then. Not to worry, though, there are still 2 upvotes:)